# MITMProxy poor performance

Tags: python, http, networking, proxy, request

We are seeing very poor performance while using MITMProxy in Python.  We are custom forwarding requests using the `requests` Python library.

Our program uses the script mode on MITMProxy to create a custom request based on the request from a client and then return the response.  So, basically, for every request made to the proxy, a new request object is built with `requests`, then forwarded and then returned.

How can I increase the performance of MITMProxy when using it to forward requests?

Comment: This is very hard to answer without knowing what performance you are getting now, and what performance you are expecting. Also, you seem to be suggesting that the performance problem is in MITMProxy. What have you done to confirm this (e.g. tried a minimal load generator with known high performance to rule out slowness in your code or the libraries you are using).

Comment: What is the measure of "performance" here for you (I am guessing response time)? MITMProxy is not meant to provide high performance solution. Infact, go ahead and read how MITMProxy works (http://mitmproxy.org/doc/howmitmproxy.html) and you will find out yourself why expecting high performance from MITMProxy is not fair. MITMProxy can internally make several requests (specially for https traffic), you seem to add another requests object layer on top of that.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue with Juan a while ago, but having received similar questions lately, let me leave the solution here for reference:

mitmproxy has a single flow primitive, so when an inline script is handling something, other requests block. Scripts can be run threaded by using the `libmproxy.script.concurrent` decorator. For more details, have a look at the [docs](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/scripting/inlinescripts.html).

(Full disclosure: I authored this feature)

Comment: The doc says: Please note that this generally opens the door to race conditions and decreases performance if not required.